# Is there any way to export fusion chart in excel using custom export buttons?

Tags: php, excel, charts, export, fusioncharts

I am using fusioncharts/3.2.4 library for rendering charts on webpage. I searched on google but could not find an answer to how can I export fusion charts in excel/PDF using custom export buttons?

**Note:** I dont want to use any builtin library aswell.

I searched and found that fusioncharts/3.2.4 does not provide native excel export functionality.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://www.fusioncharts.com/dev/exporting-charts/exporting-chart-data.html

Answer (score 0):

i'm working with the 3.11.3 and doesn't appear any at the XLS but the PNG and PDF work well.

but this can answer your question: [i found something that can help you](http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/543346/export-excel-option-not-working-fusion-chart-reports)

Answer (score 0):

You can explicitly use action based framework for this and export the excel in the way you want. I have used Apache POI for this, but you can use any of the library for this.

If you want the image of this chart as a part of excel, you can create the string of chart with the use of any backend technology and embed it with a static html content, making static html file.
Test the file by opening in browser, if it is same as that of your application expectation.

Then use 'wkhtmltoimage-0.12.5-1.exe' to generate graph image with proper wait time, and embed this generated image inthe new sheet of the excel file.